# How do i connect AWS RDS to mysql Kubernetes Pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

So i have launched a wordpress by following the documentation provided from https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/ but i see that the mysql is running as a pod, but my requirement to connect the running mysql pod to AWS rds so that i can dump my existing info into it.Please guide me

```
pod/wordpress-5f444c8849-2rsfd        1/1     Running   0          27m
pod/wordpress-mysql-ccc857f6c-7hj9m   1/1     Running   0          27m

NAME                      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                               PORT(S)        AGE
service/kubernetes        ClusterIP      10.100.0.1       <none>                                                                    443/TCP        29m
service/wordpress         LoadBalancer   10.100.148.152   a4a868cfc752f41fdb4397e3133c7001-1148081355.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   80:32116/TCP   27m
service/wordpress-mysql   ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                                    3306/TCP       27m

NAME                              READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/wordpress         1/1     1            1           27m
deployment.apps/wordpress-mysql   1/1     1            1           27m

NAME                                        DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/wordpress-5f444c8849        1         1         1       27m
replicaset.apps/wordpress-mysql-ccc857f6c   1         1         1       27m
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have mysql running on K9s as a cluster ip service, which is accessible only inside the cluster via it's own ip.

```
wordpress-mysql:3306
```

you can double check your database recreating your service as NodePort, then you  would be able to connect via SQL Administrator like Workbench, then you would be able to admin it...
here is an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0uIvplOqJM